# How to get correlation matrix for Scala dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, cross-correlation

I have Scala dataframe with numeric data:

```
df2_num.printSchema

root
 |-- ot2_total_sum: decimal(38,18) (nullable = true)
 |-- s42_3: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- s109_5: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- is_individual: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- s118_5: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- s46_3: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- ot1_nds_10: decimal(38,18) (nullable = true)
 |-- s45_3: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- s10_3: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- nb: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- s80_5: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- ot2_nds_10: decimal(38,18) (nullable = true)
 |-- pr: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- IP: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- s70_5: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- ot1_sum_without_nds: decimal(38,18) (nullable = true)
 |-- s109_3: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- s60_3: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- s190_3: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- ot3_total_sum: decimal(38,18) (nullable = true)
 |-- s130_3: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- region: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- s170_3: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- s20_3: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- s90_5: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- ot2_nds_20: decimal(38,18) (nullable = true)
 |-- s70_3: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- ot1_nds_0: decimal(38,18) (nullable = true)
 |-- s200_3: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- ot2_sum_without_nds: decimal(38,18) (nullable = true)
 |-- ot1_nds_20: decimal(38,18) (nullable = true)
 |-- s120_3: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- s150_3: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- s40_3: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- s10_5: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- nalog: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- ot1_total_sum: decimal(38,18) (nullable = true)
```

I need to get correlation matrix for all columns of this dataframe.
I've tried to use org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.Statistics.corr . It reqiues RDD data , so I've converted my dataframe to RDD

```
val df2_num_rdd =  df2_num.rdd
```

Then I try to use Statistics.cor , and get error:

```
val correlMatrix = Statistics.corr(df2_num_rdd , "pearson")

<console>:82: error: overloaded method value corr with alternatives:
  (x: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[java.lang.Double],y: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[java.lang.Double])scala.Double <and>
  (x: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[scala.Double],y: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[scala.Double])scala.Double <and>
  (X: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector],method: String)org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Matrix
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row], String)
       val correlMatrix = Statistics.corr(df2_num_rdd , "pearson")
```

So how I need to handle my data for Statistics.corr ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running a relatively recent version of Spark, I suggest using `org.apache.spark.ml.stat.Correlation.corr` instead.

First, you have to assemble the columns for which you want to compute correlation, and then you can get correlations as a dataframe. From here, you can fetch the first row and transform it to whatever suits your needs.
Here is an example :

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
import org.apache.spark.ml.stat.Correlation

val assembled: DataFrame = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(df2_num.columns)
    .setOutputCol("correlations")
    .transform(df2_num)
val correlations: DataFrame = 
    Correlation.corr(assembled, column = "correlations", method = "pearson")
```

Here are some useful links for guides related to this approach :

- [Spark MLlib Guide : Correlation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-statistics.html#correlation)
- [Spark MLlib Guide : VectorAssembler](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features#vectorassembler)

Comment: Thanks! It's worging . But I can't use the result . How to get numbers from dataframe "correlations" ?

I tried:
correlations.take(1)(0)(0)

And got Any object: 
Any =
1.0                    -8.324911678513317E-5   ... (37 total)
-8.324911678513317E-5  1.0                     ...

What can I do with any object ? How to getn numbers from it ?

Comment: Well, you can use a dense matrix for example, using `val matrix = correlations.first.getAs[DenseMatrix]` or even an array of array if you prefer. If this helps, please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

.getAs[DenseMatrix] in correlations.first.getAs[DenseMatrix] throwing an error.

@H.Leger - How would you convert the final result to a proper matrix of this format

| Column | c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c1 | 1 | 0.97 | 0.92 |
| c2 | 0.97 | 1 | 0.94 |
| c3 | 0.92 | 0.94 | 1 |